# Find what in a list (imported from Excel) is from the highest/lowest row - Python3

Tags: python

so what I've done so far is had to import a few random rows from excel and guess which one is higher/lower in the list; the correct answer being the highest row. So I have my rows importing and printing correctly but now I need to find a way to set the correct answer being the highest row (between 1, 78) from the spreadsheet.

ex.

```
example = random.sample (example, 3)
print ('a) ' + (example [0]))
print ('b) ' + (example [1]))
print ('c) ' + (example [2]))
input ('example answer= a, b or c?')
CorrectAnswer=input
if CorrectAnswer = True ...
```

Any ideas how to set up the correct and incorrect answers or maybe a nudge in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Generally capital letters as in CorrectAnswer are reserved for class names in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing your 'row' numbers in a list you can just use the sort method on the list:

```
example.sort()
answer = example[-1]
```

You can also iterate through the numbers and store the highest one:

```
answer = 0
for x in example:
    if x > answer:
        answer = x
```

This is the slowest way to find the highest number; I believe that Python uses one of the faster sorting algorithms for the sort method.